# How to remove last comma from csv file and add string in to it in SQL server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have csv file in SQL

```
@code varchar(10) = 'pc-shr,pqr,qzcx,rtde,rz-fg,kj-hl,jk_lm'
```

I tried

```
Convert(Varchar(10), @code) + CASE WHEN len(@code) >10 THEN '..etc' Else  '' END [code]
```

but I want like this means to find last comma in a string and after that add ..etc
it should look like this

'pc-shr,pqr, ..etc'

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SET @code= 
    CASE WHEN LEN(@code) > 10 
        THEN SUBSTRING(@code, 0, 10) + ', etc...' 
        ELSE '' 
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19376)**

```
declare @code varchar(10) = 'pc-shr,pqr,qzcx,rtde,rz-fg,kj-hl,jk_lm'
select @code
--pc-shr,pqr

SELECT SUBSTRING(@code, 1, LEN(@code)-CHARINDEX (',' ,REVERSE(@code))) + '..etc'
--pc-shr..etc
```

Replacing right part of string where is last comma, if you want results like in your example increase size - `varchar(11)`

**EDIT**: you want this?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@code, 1, LEN(@code)-CHARINDEX (',' ,REVERSE(@code))+1) + '..etc'
--pc-shr,..etc
```

Last comma in a string `@code varchar(10)` is this  pc-shr**,**pqr so I add `..etc` to it

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@code, 1, LEN(@code)-CHARINDEX (',' ,REVERSE(@code))+1) + '..etc ' 
   +  SUBSTRING(@code, LEN(@code)-CHARINDEX (',' ,REVERSE(@code))+2,LEN(@code)) 
--pc-shr,..etc pqr
```

Comment: no i want to get last comma from string that is of varchar(10) and add ..etc to it

Comment: I edites answer and I want to add that last comma in a string @code varchar(10) is this pc-shr*,*pqr

Answer (score 1):

The main problem i found that is your variable declaration i.e. **@code varchar(10)**. It fixes its size to 10. You can try belwo :

```
Declare @code varchar(max) = 'pc-shr,pqr,qzcx,rtde,rz-fg,kj-hl,jk_lm';    
IF LEN(@code) > 10 
BEGIN
    SET @code=SUBSTRING(@code, 0, 10) + ', etc...' 
END
```